# How do you scope the arguments scope?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

This is a JavaScript question.

In ColdFusion, we use `arguments.CustID` when referring to `CustID` that was passed to a function.

Q: Is there any way in JavaScript to refer to the scope of a parameter so that 6 months from now I know that "This variable is in the arguments scope"?

I'm considering adding `arg` to the beginning of my variable names, so that I would have `argCustID`.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: you could start passing your arguments as an object. args = { arg1: hello, arg2: world }. then inside your functions you would use args.arg1 just like your coldfusion example.

Comment: Thanks Decker.  That's a good idea. I do something similar in ColdFusion where I pass the form scope sometimes.

Comment: @Miguel-F, hmmm... There's a lot to read and comprehend with that link.  Was there something in particular you wanted me to see?

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: Kinda.  I think he's asking from the calling perspective: How can I name parameters.

Comment: I just thought the highest rated answer on that page showed some good examples of the different scopes in javascript. I realize it doesn't really answer your question but I thought it might give you better insight to how the scopes behave.  @DeckerWBrower might have the best suggestion for you.

Comment: Arguments in js functions can also be accessed by their numerical indexes, e.g. `arguments[0]`. But I believe what you want is to pass an object, as Brower suggested.