# DocuSign optional parameter node js sdk

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

How to specify the optional parameter in update node js sdk method. Update ( account ID, envelope I'd , envelope obj )

Comment: unclear what you are asking exactly. Can you explain further. Which method, which parameter, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You just add the parameter you want to the call

so, if there's an optional parameter in a method method1, you can call it like this:

```
method1(param1, param2, param3);
```

(where if param3 is optional you can also call it like this:)

```
method1(param1, param2);
```

you can also (See here - [Is there a way to provide named parameters in a function call in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/is-there-a-way-to-provide-named-parameters-in-a-function-call-in-javascript)) specify the names of the parameters:

```
method1(param1 - "param1", param2: "param2");
```