# Why does JavaScript not have named parameters?

Tags: javascript, parameters, named-parameters

Named parameters (i.e. `fnCall(x = "something")`) are very useful for visually verifying you are passing the correct item in the correct spot (among other reasons to use them.)

JS doesn't natively support them. [This article already covers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript) the work arounds, what I'm curious is *why* JS doesn't support name parameters? (when most? other programming languages seem to)

Comment: Here is a discussion from 4 years ago: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/named-paramters

Comment: "*most other programming languages seem to*" - [citation needed]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/