# Cannot find data-testid attribute in Vue Component with Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to build a test that will target an element with the **data-testid** attribute. I have a BaseTile component that looks like this:

```
<template>
      <div
        data-testid="base-tile-icon"
        v-if="!!this.$slots.icon"
      >
        <slot name="icon"></slot>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style></style>
```

And my test looks like this:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BaseTile from '@/components/BaseTile';

const factory = (slot = 'default') => {
  return mount(BaseTile, {
    slots: {
      [slot]: '<div class="test-msg"></div>'
    }
  });
};

it('has an icon slot if an icon is provided', () => {
  let wrapper = factory({ slot: 'icon' });
  const input = wrapper.find('[data-testid="base-tile-icon"]');
  expect(input.findAll('.test-msg').length).toBe(1);
});
```

How do I appropriately target the **data-testid** attribute with this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named parameter of the factory is implemented incorrectly. The correct method is described in this post: [Is there a way to provide named parameters in a function call in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/is-there-a-way-to-provide-named-parameters-in-a-function-call-in-javascript)

The correct way to implement this is as follows:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BaseTile from '@/components/BaseTile';

const factory = ({ slot = 'default' } = {}) => {
  return mount(BaseTile, {
    slots: {
      [slot]: '<div class="test-msg"></div>'
    }
  });
};

it('has an icon slot if an icon is provided', () => {
  let wrapper = factory({ slot: 'icon' });
  const input = wrapper.find('[data-testid="base-tile-icon"]');
  expect(input.findAll('.test-msg').length).toBe(1);
});
```