# hand over only some of the additional Variables for function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

sorry for my terrible english

I have a funtion like this

```
function E(element1, element2 = "yes", element3="no")
{
console.log(`E1: ${element1}\nE2: ${element2}\nE3: ${element3}`)
}
```

When I call this function, I only wanna change the thrid element and the second can stay the same
Something like this `E("test", stay, "yes")`

Thanks

Comment: The parameters are not changing anything.  They are defaulting values if a value is not given for the parameter.  If you don't want something to "change", either pass it in, or take off the default value on the parameter list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer for some help: [Is there a way to provide named parameters in a function call in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796776/1913726)

I rewrote your function as follows:

```
//In ES2015, parameter destructuring can be used to simulate named parameters.

function E(element1, {element2="yes", element3="no"}={}){
    console.log(`E1: ${element1}\nE2: ${element2}\nE3: ${element3}`);
}

// call E without a value for element2. The default is used.
E("test", {element3: "foo"})
```

Output:

> E1: test

> E2: yes

> E3: foo

Answer (score 2):

The function E should already do what you are asking for.

The `element2 = "yes"` syntax is setting the **default** value of the `element2` variable, when that variable is null. If you call the function just like your example `E("test", stay, "yes")`, the value of `stay` will not be changed, unless its value is null.

If you want to keep a `null` value, just remove the `= "yes"` part.

Answer (score 1):

## sugesstion

use key-value form when passing arguments to your funtion.
It will be lot more fexible.

```
   function E(variable)
    {
    
    console.log(`E1: ${variable.element1}\nE2: ${variable.element2}\nE3: ${variable.element3}`)
    }

E( {"element1" : "no","element2":"yes", "element3" : "no"} )
```