# Do I have to address JavaScript function variables in order? How to do it?

Tags: javascript

How do I send one or more variables in a JavaScript function without sending null values to unused arguments?

I have a function:

```
function setProjectParameters(trigger, pp_ts, pp_t, pp_bs, pp_dg, pp_ll){alert("the rest of the code is here doing something");}
```

Sometimes I want to call this function and only send a value to `pp_bs`, now I do it like this:

```
setProjectParameters(null,null,null,"8");
```

Can I do it something like this?: (It doesn't work so I guess not...)

```
setProjectParameters(pp_ts="44");
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: What _language_? In JavaScript, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11796093/3001761. Note `undefined` is likely better than `null` for "no value", as that's the default for parameters _after_ the last supplied positional value.

Comment: thanks, I should have written that it's about Javascript

Comment: As far as I know JavaScript doesn't support that. You can however "simulate" this if you change the function to accept an object and use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) e.g. `function setProjectParameters({ trigger, pp_ts, pp_t, pp_bs, pp_dg, pp_ll })` and then call it as e.g. `setProjectParameters({ pp_ts: '44' })`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest I think is to have the parameters in the function as an object and have defaults for them if you need to. Then you can target a specific parameter.

```
function setProjectParameters({trigger = 'if you need defaults add them like this', pp_ts, pp_t, pp_bs, pp_dg, pp_ll}){alert("the rest of the code is here doing something");}
```

Then use the function like this

```
setProjectParameters({pp_ts="44"});
```