# Is there a way to nest simulated named parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, destructuring, named-parameters

## Background

I am creating a function that handles dom manipulation such as creating an element, adding/setting some properties on the element, and appending it to a parent. I wanted to use named parameters, but from my research I found that this feature is not built into JS. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/is-there-a-way-to-provide-named-parameters-in-a-function-call-in-javascript) helped me "simulate" named parameters with [parameter destructuring](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6) and I was able to get it working successfully:

```js
const createElement = function createNewDomElement({
        parent, 
        tag,
        idName, 
        className,
        innerHTML,
        href
    }={}) {
    
    if (parent) {
        console.log(parent);  // Works
    }

}
```

Visual studio code provides a hint that shows me which params are available:

[image]

## Problem and Attempted Solution

As some of these parameters are required and the rest are optional, I would like to separate the optional parameters into a separate object within the function parameter object without losing the Visual Studio hint that shows which params are available. I tried to do this with:

```js
const createElement = function createNewDomElement({
        tag,
        options: {
            parent, 
            idName, 
            className,
            innerHTML,
            href
        }
    }={}) {
    
    if (options) {
        options.forEach(item => console.log(item));
    }

}
```

However, when I try to access the options the same way as I was able to access the parent parameter in the first example, it says it is not defined.

## Question

Is there a way to nest simulated named parameters in a way that maintains the Visual Studio Code hint showing which parameters are available?

I am also open to solutions which work, but where I lose the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to iterate those attributes but you can access it in this way

```
function createElement({
        tag,
        options: {
            parent, 
            idName, 
            className,
            innerHTML,
            href
        }
    } = { options: {} }) {
    
    if (parent) {
        console.log(parent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, in your example I'm able to access `parent` from within options just using `parent` and not `options.parent`. Is it also possible to access `tag` and `options` the same way? Does this just take every object and nested object and create variables from their name/value pairs?

Comment: Exactly, you can access `tag` in the same way but everything under `options` will be accessible by the attribute name only, so you cannot do `options.something`