# Difference in listing variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript)

I was wondering whether there is a difference in listing variables in JavaScript (and JS libraries).

**Example**:

```
var $this = $(this),
    $body = $("body"),
    $main-wrap = $("body > section.wrapper");
```

**OR**

```
var $this = $(this);
var $body = $("body");
var $main-wrap = $("body > section.wrapper");
```

I always thought that the difference only lies in notation. The first example is shorter and possibly faster to execute. Recently I did some testing and now I am not sure anymore. Can anyone clear this up?

Is there a difference in execution speed, result, method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke the habit of using multiple `var` statements when I started using [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com).  It always caught that and said that it was faster to separate by a comma.

Looking into this more, there seem to be many sources that agree with this.

**From [jsLint #scope](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#scope)**

> It is recommended that a single var statement be used per function.

**From [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-minification-part-II/):**

> The var statement defines one or more variables. Sometimes you’ll see code that looks like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
```

> This code defines two variables, one
>   right after the other. I often see this pattern for 10 or more
>   variables in a row. Doing so artificially inflates the size of your
>   code because multiple var statements can be combined into one using a
>   comma operator:

```
var image = document.getElementById("myImage"),
div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
```

> This code also defines two variables
>   and provides the same initialization. However, you’ve saved the three
>   bytes that another var would have cost. Three bytes might not seem
>   like a big deal, but if you’re able to find dozens of places where
>   there’s currently an extra var statement, the savings can really add
>   up.

**However,**

here are two fairly compelling reasons to use multiple `var` statements from [SO posters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript). [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672635/javascript-var-statement-and-performance)

Answer (score 4):

That's not jQuery that just plain-jane JavaScript variable declaration.

As far as a difference, there isn't one. The only speed increase you could acquire would be to stop spinning up multiple jQuery objects and re-reference existing ones for further processing. e.g.

```
var body = $('body'),
    wrapper = body.children('section.wrapper');
```

See also [JavaScript variable definition: Commas vs. Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons)

Comment: Edited the question :) Thanks for your answer, I'll see what the others say.

Comment: body.children('section.wrapper') is faster :) as soon as selector is body > section

Comment: @acrashik: Good call. Still waking up (pre-coffee) and glanced over the direct descendant selector. ;-)